# cmd.stdin.flush() IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Basically i'm running massive python script that runs for hours.

Oftenly i'm using the the Commit object like `repo.commit(some_valid_hexsah)`.

I'm using it over and over again, and doing lots of stuff in between.

For unknown reason, after some time, I'm getting:

```
File "C:\Users\amirelm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gitpython-3.0.1-py2.7.egg\git\repo\base.py", line 482, in commit
    return self.rev_parse(text_type(rev) + "^0")
  File "C:\Users\amirelm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gitpython-3.0.1-py2.7.egg\git\repo\fun.py", line 213, in rev_parse
    obj = name_to_object(repo, rev[:start])
  File "C:\Users\amirelm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gitpython-3.0.1-py2.7.egg\git\repo\fun.py", line 150, in name_to_object
    return Object.new_from_sha(repo, hex_to_bin(hexsha))
  File "C:\Users\amirelm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gitpython-3.0.1-py2.7.egg\git\objects\base.py", line 64, in new_from_sha
    oinfo = repo.odb.info(sha1)
  File "C:\Users\amirelm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gitpython-3.0.1-py2.7.egg\git\db.py", line 37, in info
    hexsha, typename, size = self._git.get_object_header(bin_to_hex(sha))
  File "C:\Users\amirelm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gitpython-3.0.1-py2.7.egg\git\cmd.py", line 1077, in get_object_header
    return self.__get_object_header(cmd, ref)
  File "C:\Users\amirelm\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gitpython-3.0.1-py2.7.egg\git\cmd.py", line 1065, in __get_object_header
    cmd.stdin.flush()
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I have no idea why this is happening, if some one knows how to explain this error or expeienced something similiar I would appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the script remotely, over ssh or such?

Comment: No, I'm running it on a pc